# How to decipher traffic from syslog-ng to syslog

Tags: logging, tags, syslog, rsyslog, syslog-ng

I have a centralized syslog-ng system that is taking in feeds from various servers, and putting it into storage.  Fortunately, I was forward thinking and I have each system coming in on its own port, which helps me delineate which traffic is which.

I need to send some of this traffic to a network sensor running rsyslogd.  But that sensor is only listening on 514, and I can't change that. But I need for the rsyslogd box to be able to pull apart the traffic, and to know where it came from originally, so that I can apply the right rewriting and sending to software on the sensor (basically, to template it all).

How can I do this?  I know there is tagging on the syslog-ng box, but from what I see, that doesn't actually work for outbound UDP traffic.

Answer (score 0):

If you use UDP, you can use the spoof-source() option of syslog-ng. It needs a syslog-ng package compiled with libnet. For details check the documentation at https://www.balabit.com/sites/default/files/documents/syslog-ng-ose-3.7-guides/en/syslog-ng-ose-v3.7-guide-admin/html-single/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply Peter.  I've tried this.  I have spoof-source(yes) set, and recompiled syslog-ng with the --enable-spoof-source flag.  But it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: I also tried adding in a tag into the message on the syslog-ng side, and then using `if $msg contains 'mytag'` in a .conf file on the rsylog.d side, but that doesn't seem to work as well.  I can tcpdump the traffic and see the tag in the message, but rsyslogd isn't pulling out the traffic and putting it into the log file I want.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately, tags are not part of the message by default. To send over tags to a destination, you have to explicitly put them in the destination template.